# Which counter do you use for counting TV series episodes?

Tags: counters

I want to say "I saw 10 episodes", but I can't find the appropriate counter.

I may use "つ" counter (十エピソードを見ました), but it's not very classy.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I believe that the usual counter is 話{わ}, literally meaning *stories*, so you'd say 10話 for ten episodes, and 第10話 or 10話目 for the tenth episode.

Occasionally I've seen shows that used different counters for their own title cards.  For example, ふしぎの海のナディア numbered all its episodes using 回, so for instance the tenth episode was 第10回.  And 神秘の世界エルハザード numbered its episodes with 夜 instead, possibly in reference to *1,001 Nights* (千夜一夜物語).

But of course you can always use 話 as the counter when *you* talk about these shows, no matter how they number their own episodes.

Comment: "ふしぎの海のナディア numbered all its episodes using 回" Trick 2 did the same thing, but only for it's promos I think.