# How to say "Episode 22", "Chapter 22", "Act 22", etc?

Tags: numbers, counters

I just wanted to make sure that my understanding is correct.

When saying Chapter 22, Act 22, or Episode 22 (basically parts of a larger piece), it normally starts with 第22 (or 第[number]) and then the counter. Right? And 第 is another way of saying 目? Basically -th, ie.: fifth, sixth, second, first, ninth. So all I need is the counter for the word I'm using. For instance, the counter for "chapter" is: 章. And the counter for "episode", [according to this thread](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/12832/which-counter-did-you-use-for-counting-tv-series-episodes), is: 話.

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 6):

You are correct on `話` for "episode" and `章` for "chapter" (the Bible in Japanese uses `章` for chapter).  I'm not sure about "act", but multiple searches show `[幕]{まく}`.  Also related is `[巻]{かん}` for "volume" and `[場]{ば}` for "scene".

Comment: ie the first act of a play = 劇の第1幕 (which is logical as the curtain often comes down at the end of an act to change the scenery). Seems that 段 can also be used for scene (which is logical as an act is split up into sections)